# MongoDB: 'connection attempts failed' while doing remote access

Tags: database, mongodb

I want others to access mongoDB on my OS X, the firewall is off and my configuration file is like:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
```

and i start the service like

```
sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

I can always access the database using `mongo` and `mongo 127.0.0.1`

but when i use  `mongo xx.xxx.xxx.xxx(my ip address)`

the access fails with the report:

```
mongo xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
MongoDB shell version v3.4.17
connecting to: mongodb://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/test
2018-10-04T09:05:54.316+0800 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-10-04T09:05:54.317+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I'm really puzzled here. Obviously it's a timeout but my network connection is ok. I used homebrew to install mongoDB, and i've tried every version from 3.0 to 4.0 and the result seems always the same. And Google didn't give any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mongodb version and environment info.

```
root@Backup:~# mongod --version
db version v3.2.22
git version: 105acca0d443f9a47c1a5bd608fd7133840a58dd
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

What I did is to update 
`bindIp: 0.0.0.0` in both files: `/etc/mongod.conf` and `/etc/mongodb.conf`. After the service restart, I could be able to connect mongodb remotely.